# Controller Cannot Be Found In Directive Error

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm getting the following error in my console:

> Error: [$compile:ctreq] Controller 'gamesList', required by directive
>   'searchTerm', can't be found!

Here's the code that I'm using:

**The Game List:**

```
<div class = "bit-75-percent games-list" data-ng-controller = "GamesController">
    <ng-include src = "'../templates/simpleSearch.tpl.html'"></ng-include>
    <div class = "game" data-ng-repeat = "game in games" data-games-list>
        {{game.name}}
    </div>
</div>
```

**The Search Form:**

```
<form class = "simple-search" data-ng-controller ="SearchController">
    <input type = "text" name = "search-term" class = "search-term" data-search-term>
    <div data-pane></div>
</form>
```

**The Games Directive**

```
(function(window, angular, undefined) {
    var app;

    app = angular.module('games');

    app.directive('gamesList', function(GamesService) {
        console.log('Loaded gamesList directive');
        return {
            controller: function(scope) {
                scope.updateGamesList = function(gamesList) {
                    scope.games = gamesList;
                };
            },
            restrict: 'A',
            scope: {},
            transclude: true
        };
    });
}(window, window.angular));
```

**The Search Directive:**

```
(function(window, angular, undefined) {
    var app;

    app = angular.module('search');

    app.directive('searchTerm', function(GamesService) {
        console.log('Loaded searchTerm directive');
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            require: 'gamesList',
            scope: {},
            transclude: true,
            link: function(scope, element, attr) {
                element.on('keyup', function() {
                    GamesService.query();
                });
            }
        };
    });
}(window, window.angular));
```

**What I've Tried and/or Double Checked**

1. Alternating between specifying a `scope` and not for each directive.
2. Making sure that the `gamesList` directive is loaded before `searchTerm`
3. Making sure both directives are getting loaded.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: try `require : "^gamesList"`. see the difference [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile)

Answer (score 0):

The `require` property of directive definition object allows to be sure that you have specified directive(s) on the same element or in any his parents. It can't be used for check that specified directive exists anywhere on a page.

BTW, controller's parameters resolved by `$injector` service and should be named properly: `$scope` but not the `scope`